# trying to draw some simple lines in android

Tags: android, draw

i am trying to draw some lines via code on top of a background image to make a sort of graph-like thing, but i can't seem to find a method to do this, can anyone help?

*edit here is what i have so far, but i get a force close on the line Canvas canvas

*edit2 sorry for ignorance on my part, i am new to this, i've not used logcat before.  i opened logcat and it appears that it might be a "immutable bitmap passed to canvas constructor".  after some googling, i think this is getting to be beyond the scope of what i am capable of, i didn't realize drawing was this involved.  thanks for the help anyways all.

```
package com.surreall;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas; 
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class drawline extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

// load picture and create a canvas to draw onto


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);  
// set drawing colour
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.felt2);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
//Paint p = new Paint();
//p.setColor(Color.RED);

// draw a line onto the canvas
//canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 50, 50, p);
}
}
```

Comment: for this type of drawing u have to use canvas:you can find more references from this [link](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-use-canvas-your-android-apps-part-2).its useful for ur requirements.

Comment: a tip for the next question you might ask: never just tell "there is a force close" please provide the error message from the LogCat.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want something along the lines of:

```
// load picture and create a canvas to draw onto
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("my_pretty_picture.png");
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

// set drawing colour
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setColor(Color.RED);

// draw a line onto the canvas
canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 50, 50, p);
```

The rest is for you to fill in :)

Comment: where and how do i load the png file?  do i just need it in my drawable folder, or do i need it already loaded?

Comment: The sample code above uses a relative pathname ('my_pretty_picture.png'). If your resource is at `res/drawable/picture.png`, try changing my code to use `BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.picture)`.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i tried adding your suggestion, and i get a force close still.  i tried commenting out all but the first line and it runs, but when i uncomment the "Canvas canvas" line i get a force close.

Comment: Look at the Logcat output. This will indicate where the error in your program is, I'm not going to code it all for you!